# AWS sdk cloudwatch GetMetricWidgetImage: no result shows in the image

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using React to build a simple metrics dashboard which gets snapshot images from CloudWatch using `aws-sdk`. The problem is returned images shows no actual values, like:

[image]

Whereas the image in aws console cloudwatch shows a blue line.

Here's my request:

```
         cloudwatch
            .getMetricWidgetImage({
              MetricWidget: JSON.stringify({
                title: "Website CPU Utilizition",
                view: "timeSeries",
                stacked: false,
                metrics: [
                  [
                    "AWS/ECS",
                    "CPUUtilization",
                    "ServiceName",
                    "website",
                    "ClusterName",
                    "sxl-c-website-service"
                  ]
                ],
                start: "-PT3H",
                end: "P0D"
              })
            })
```

Then I convert the response to base64 and renders the img.

Have confirmed the two axes are the same with the chart in cloudwatch console, there's just no result, getting an empty chart as above.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an image back, so that's good. And you can see the data in CloudWatch console, right?

This means CloudWatch can't find data for your metric. First things to check are:

- Are you calling the correct region? Request needs to be made against CloudWatch endpoint in the region where your metric is.
- Are you using the credentials from the correct account?